# Why didn't the Bug just kill J and K after taking their weapons?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black

During the climax of *Men in Black*, the two agents shot the ship the Bug was using to escape and brought him back to the ground. As soon as the Bug was out, he took away their weapons and showed them his true form. Then he just pushed the agents away and started walking the other way. He swallowed Agent K after he insisted a lot, but still basically let Agent J live.

I am confused. We know how powerful and dangerous the Bug is. It already killed two other aliens in the cafeteria earlier in the movie. So why not just kill J and K before going for the other ship?

Answer (score 3):

Despite having real issues with impulse control, Edgar has a duty to perform, transporting the Galaxy offworld to his hive. Getting into a pointless fight with vermin might have its attractions, but he has bigger fish to fry.

> In that, the human female had been right. The responsibilities of
> being a father demanded much and he was a good father, if he did say
> so himself. Better than most. He'd like to see Merg or Barl or even
> Revo stuffed into one of these human suits for ten heartbeats. They'd
> go mad and start trashing everything they could lay a pincher on, he
> was sure of it, and Demons take their families. **Not him. He knew where
> his duties lay. He did what was necessary, loathsome as it was at
> times. He might have had to do worse in the past than this, but
> offpincher, he couldn't remember so doing.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black - The Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2010110.Men_in_Black?ref=nav_sb_ss_3_18)</sup></sub>

Don't forget that the clock is ticking. In a few minutes the Earth is going to get vapourised.

> Kerb—he no longer had to think of himself as the Edgar now, thank any
> and all the gods—paused in his excavation of the saucer. Perhaps he
> should just climb the other tower and take the second ship?
>
> No, better to use this one. It was closer, he was in a hurry, and that
> little fall shouldn't have damaged it.
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black - The Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2010110.Men_in_Black?ref=nav_sb_ss_3_18)</sup></sub>

As you say, it's only when Kay directly taunts him that he gives in to his baser urges. Note how the humans are described in the script. Edgar might be a bug, but he sees Jay and Kay as the lesser-evolved creatures, barely worthy of his time.

> The Bug SWIPES at them with the back of his clawed hand, like someone
> brushing aside a gnat -- and SENDS THEM FLYING FIFTEEN FEET IN THE AIR.
>
> <sub><sup>[Men in Black - Screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Men-in-Black.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: OK, so the fact that "bug" killed 2 aliens in a blink earlier in the movie, and then when J crushes some bugs he came down and stopped climbing to the second ship (earth about to be destroyed in few minutes) and just started staring at J, it just looks like poor writing. I mean come-on "bug", just slice them and get going. Also, the humans didn't know that alien ship (that "bug" arrived in) had crashed for quite sometime. That also seem like a plot hole. Also, the fact that the galaxy was in that thing worn by cat, why put something so precious around a cat rather than in a vault?

Comment: @quantum231 - Those are some fine questions that you could [ask](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: For some people it is really precious, for others it is just a marble just for playing in the sand

Comment: @quantum231 There's truth in television to hiding precious things in plain sight. For that matter, it was successful, the bug overlooked the bauble on the cat's collar.

Comment: I saw MIB 1 and MIB 2; they are ok movies but did not feel great. I guess they were quite impressive when they came out? In the MIB 2, the alien got a flying machine to pursue MIB somehow and then kept shooting at her? MIB take their flying car into subway tunnel and suddenly stop inspite of moving at insane speeds. The MIB thought that the worm will not let the alien out, really? The alient was shown to be quite powerful in MIB 2 but still somehow got taken down by 1 gun shot each time? So many weaknesses in the plot.